# Jmeter version 5.5 not storing debug logs in jtl file

Tags: testing, automation, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

When I set the log level in UI to debug/trace, the jtl file is still storing the data with only info logs but showing the debug logs in UI. I even modified the log4j2 configuration file and tried the below

```
jmeter -Lorg.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control=DEBUG
jmeter -Lorg.apache.http=DEBUG
jmeter -LDEBUG
```

This also is not storing the debug logs, I'm simply trying to get the request/response parameters completely stored for every single request that we are making in our test plan. What am I missing? Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration increases JMeter logging verbosity so [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file has more details comparing to [default configuration](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/bin/log4j2.xml)

If you want to save request and response details there are 2 options:

1. Amend JMeter's [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) to look like:

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
   jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
   jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
   jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
   jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
   jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
   ```
2. Or add a listener like [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) and choose what and where to store

   [image]

More information: [How to Save Response Data in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-data-in-jmeter)